# Android / Cloudboost : Append every user to column of a specific row

Tags: android, list, cloudboost

I want to append the current user of every one who taps the button to a the column of type list so that later I can just get the length of how many people pressed it.

This is my code:

```
public void findAnswered(CloudQuery query) throws CloudException {
    query.findById(questionID, new CloudObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(CloudObject object, CloudException e) throws CloudException {
            if (object != null) {
                Log.i("---------FIND ANS QUERY", "SUCCESS I: " + object.getID());
                answered(object);
            }
            if (e != null) {
                Log.i("---------FIND ANS QUERY", "ERROR: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}

public void answered(CloudObject object) throws CloudException {
    CloudObject [] user = {CloudUser.getcurrentUser()};

    Log.i("------UPDATE ANS OBJECT", "A: " + this.answered);
    Log.i("------UPDATE ANS OBJECT", "W: " + this.wrongAnswer);
    Log.i("------UPDATE ANS OBJECT", "R: " + this.rightAnswer);

    object.set("earnings", earnings);
    object.set("dividend", dividend);
    object.set("answered", user);
    if (this.wrongAnswer == 1) {
        object.set("wrong", user);
    }
    if (this.rightAnswer == 1) {
        object.set("right", user);
    }

    object.save(new CloudObjectCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(CloudObject object, CloudException e) throws CloudException {
            if (object != null) {
                // Success
                Log.i("------UPDATE ANS OBJECT", "SUCCESS I: " + object.getId());
            }
            if (e != null) {
                // Error
                Log.i("------UPDATE ANS ERROR:", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when i try to do it on two phones, it only adds the first user who clicked it and skips the second. How do I keep adding users to the same box?

Comment: let us understand your issue better: every question has an answer button and you want that every time a user presses this button, the question record is fetched and updated by adding this user to the list column called **answered**. Am I right on this?

Comment: Actually it's on a live timer when the timer is over the method gets called and then the the user gets pushed in. But always it always has one user. The user being the last one who replaces the first one. For example if I answer on my phone my user gets pushed and then on another phone that user gets pushed and it replaces my user. I want it to add every user that same second instead of just replacing each other. The positions of the user does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on this line
`CloudObject [] user = {CloudUser.getcurrentUser()};`

You are creating an array with only the current user, so that when you update the `CloudObject` with `object.set("answered", user);`
, you are simply overwriting any existing List of Users in your list column and not really **appending** current user to existing users as you actually want.
What you should be doing is to retrieve all existing users into an appropriate data structure (like an ArrayList or a Set), and **append** the current user with `users.add(CloudUser.getCurrentUser())` before updating your `CloudObject`

Comment: This still isn't working. I have it set up so that at 0:00 seconds i call and intent and on the `onStop()` method that gets called. So that for everyone playing this happens at the same time.

Comment: Since the player list is being updated from different devices more or less at the same time, they are bound to overwrite each other and this is exactly how **CloudObject.save** is supposed to work when updating.What you want to do is  a bit tricky because there is no silver bullet, you may have to use a custom work around like  improvising some sort of DB lock to take care of this during `onStop()`.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I actually figured it out. Takes a lot of more Api calls then I wanted but yeah. It does the trick. All within a second. Thanks though !